# Loop through asp:repeater items, only changes first item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating discount vouchers for a website and the cart is a Databound ASP:Repeater.

***PROBLEM*** **I can't use the built in debugger on this code as it is a live hosted IIS website (is what I'm told, I'm pretty green) and the debugger just cries when it tries to run it. Nothing reaches the SQL server and hyperlinks don't work, and this particular page will always open onto an empty cart.**

I have several vouchers working fine, but there is one type which doesn't work correctly. I want to take a csv of stockcodes and check the cart for every instance of the product.

Example string: `SP08075,sp08076,sp08077,sp08078,sp08079,sp08098`

But my voucher only affects the first matching item in the cart, and ignores the rest.

Here's the item template for my repeater:

```
<itemtemplate>

    <div class="cart-product-row">
        <div class="cart-product-id"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductID" runat="Server"></asp:HyperLink></div>
    <div class="cart-product-holder">
        <div class="cart-product"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductName" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></div>
        <div class="cart-options">
            <input name="hidden" type="hidden" id="UniqueValue" value="" runat="server" />
            <input name="hiddencat" type="hidden" id="Category" value="" runat="server" />
            <div id="divOption" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="lblOptionsName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="cart-unit-price">$<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
    <div class="cart-quantity"><asp:TextBox onfocus="this.select();" onkeypress="return noenter();" AutoPostBack="true" ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Width="30" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox></div>
    <div class="cart-price-total">$<asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
    <div class="cart-remove"><asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Remove" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></div>
</div>
<div class="cart-oos-liner"><asp:Label ID="lblOOSWarning" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
```

And here's the method that takes that string and tries to discount the correct codes.

**VB.Net**

```
    Private Sub RunStockVoucher()           'Voucher applies only to specified stock codes.
    Dim row As DataRow = vData.Rows(0)  'Get voucher data from DataTable

    'Declare variables relevant to this voucher
    Dim discount As Int32 = row("Discount")
    Dim dollarPercent As Int32 = row("DollarPercent")
    Dim stockValidCodes As String = row("stockvalidcodes")
    Dim stockAllSome As Int32 = row("stockAllSome")
    Dim stockSomeNo As Int32 = row("stockSomeNo")
    Dim codes As String() = stockValidCodes.Split(",")      'If more than one stock code is valid, split the string into an Array and remove the comma separator
    Dim num As Int32 = 0                                    'Set number to 0 for further checking.


    'For Each code As String In codes                        'Check each valid stock code agains the whole cart.
    For Each item As RepeaterItem In rptCart.Items      'Loop through every item.
        For Each code As String In codes
            'Get item properties
            Dim price As Label = CType(item.FindControl("lblPrice"), Label)
            Dim cost As Single = CSng(price.Text)
            Dim UniqueCode As HtmlInputHidden = item.FindControl("UniqueValue")
            Dim prodID As HyperLink = CType(item.FindControl("hlProductID"), HyperLink)
            Dim qty As TextBox = CType(item.FindControl("txtQuantity"), TextBox)
            Dim quant As Int32 = Int32.Parse(qty.Text)
            Dim extCode As String = New Guid().ToString()

            'If product Stock Code matches valid code run further checks, else skip to next product.
            If String.Equals(code, prodID.Text.ToString().Trim()) = True Then
                If stockAllSome = 0 Then        '0 = Discount applies to all instances of valid stock.
                    c.UpdateCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, 0)
                    If dollarPercent = 0 Then       'Apply discounts, 0= Dollar, 1 = Percentage, 2 = Fixed Price
                        c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), quant, cost - discount)
                    ElseIf dollarPercent = 1 Then
                        Dim perc As Single = discount / 100
                        Dim perc2 As Single = 1 - perc
                        c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), quant, cost * perc2)
                    ElseIf dollarPercent = 2 Then
                        c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), quant, discount)
                    End If
                Else        'ELSE discount only applies to some of the items.
                    If quant > stockSomeNo Then 'If there are more than the valid amount of the item, split into two cart items.
                        c.UpdateCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, 0)    'First item is discounted, at valid quantity
                        If dollarPercent = 0 Then
                            c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), stockSomeNo, cost - discount)
                        ElseIf dollarPercent = 1 Then
                            Dim perc As Single = discount / 100
                            Dim perc2 As Single = 1 - perc
                            c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), stockSomeNo, cost * perc2)
                        ElseIf dollarPercent = 2 Then
                            c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), stockSomeNo, discount)
                        End If

                        'Second cart item is not discounted, quantity set to remainder amount.
                        c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, extCode, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), quant - stockSomeNo, cost)
                    Else    'If quantity is less than valid number, discount all items.
                        c.UpdateCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, 0)
                        If dollarPercent = 0 Then
                            c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), quant, cost - discount)
                        ElseIf dollarPercent = 1 Then
                            Dim perc As Single = discount / 100
                            Dim perc2 As Single = 1 - perc
                            c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), quant, cost * perc2)
                        ElseIf dollarPercent = 2 Then
                            c.AddCartObject(prodID.Text, UniqueCode.Value, Product.GetProductNameByCode(prodID.Text), quant, discount)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    c.UpdateUser(c.CustomerID)  'Apply changes on Customer level (GPCUSer.vb), bind data to display changes on screen
    c.VoucherName = row("Name")
    BindData()
End Sub
```

The for each loop will successfuly discount the first matching code e.g. `SP08075` that it finds in the cart, but no matter how many other stock codes match there are no changes.

I don't think it's an error in the way the price adjustments are displayed, as I have another voucher that will discount every cart item regardless of stock code and it will loop through and discount everything just fine. I think it's something to do with the 'string.equals' setup but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: It seems a string upper/lower case issue. May be just use `ToLower()` like this: `if String.Equals(code.ToLower(), prodID.Text.Trim().ToLower())`

Comment: We have a winner, and I have have a headache. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a string upper/lower case issue. May be just use `ToLower()` like this:

```
if String.Equals(code.ToLower(), prodID.Text.Trim().ToLower())
```